# Select distinct top 4 records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server Table

I want latest all Top 4 distinct codes  from the below table
Remember I want all columns to be returned not just codes column.

```
sno  city      state  country  code  date
1    new york  NY      US      1234  1/1/2013
2    Houston   TX      US      2234  1/6/2013 
3    LA        CA      US      1123  1/2/2013
4    Chicago   IL      US      1244  1/3/2013
5    Brooklyn  NY      US      1234  1/4/2013
6    Dallas    TX      US      2234  1/5/2013
```

My following select query is returning duplicate codes, but I want distinct latest codes.

```
select top 4 * from table1 where code in (select distinct code from table1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Kenneth for editing the query and updating table

Comment: Given the example data you provided, what do you want the result to be? ***Please edit the question with that.*** Because it's not clear what exactly you're expecting - and it's a little contradicting to what's on the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WITH topList
AS
(
    SELECT  sno, city, state, country, code, date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  TOP 4 sno, city, state, country, code, date
FROM    topList
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER   BY DATE DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e337c/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════╦══════════╦═══════╦═════════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ SNO ║   CITY   ║ STATE ║ COUNTRY ║ CODE ║    DATE    ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════╬════════════╣
║   2 ║ Houston  ║ TX    ║ US      ║ 2234 ║ 1/6/2013   ║
║   5 ║ Brooklyn ║ NY    ║ US      ║ 1234 ║ 1/4/2013   ║
║   4 ║ Chicago  ║ IL    ║ US      ║ 1244 ║ 1/3/2013   ║
║   3 ║ LA       ║ CA    ║ US      ║ 1123 ║ 1/2/2013   ║
╚═════╩══════════╩═══════╩═════════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple with a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM table1
WHERE sno IN (SELECT MAX(sno) FROM table1 GROUP BY code)
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Though, this is the most recent (?) group by `sno`, not by date.